# proof of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

show that if the conditional probabilities exist then $$p(A_1\cap A_2 \cap \cdots \cap A_n) = p(A_1)p(A_2\mid A_1)p(A_3\mid A_1\cap A_2)\cdots p(A_n\mid A_1\cap A_2 \cap A_3\cap\cdots\cap A_{n-1})$$

I am lost, because if this is what i am given what do they want  e to do? Perhaps show an induction proof for the $n+1$ case?

The definition given of conditional probability is the usual $p(A\cap B) = p(A\mid B)p(B)$

Comment: Yes, I guess you are supposed to make a proof by induction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition: $Pr(A|B) := \frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$.  By multiplying each side by $Pr(B)$ we get the *multiplication principle* and our base case for induction:

$$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A|B)\cdot Pr(B)$$

Or, equivalently, by the commutativity of $\cap$ and $\cdot$, a more convenient form for our purposes:

$$Pr(A\cap B) = Pr(A)\cdot Pr(B|A)$$

Suppose for our induction hypothesis that we know how to expand the intersection of $n$ sets in terms of conditional probabilities in the form $Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots \cap A_n) = Pr(A_1)\cdot Pr(A_2|A_1)\cdot Pr(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)\cdots Pr(A_n|A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots \cap A_{n-1})$

This is certainly true when $n=2$ as shown by the definition of conditional probability and the multiplication principle above.

Now, we wish to show that if it happens to be true for some $n\geq 2$ then it must follow that it is true for $n+1$ as well.

Let $E = A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots A_n$

$Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots A_n \cap A_{n+1}) = Pr(E\cap A_{n+1}) = Pr(E)\cdot Pr(A_{n+1}|E) = Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots A_n)\cdot Pr(A_{n+1}|A_1\cap A_2\cap \cdots A_n)$

By our induction hypothesis, we know how to expand $Pr(E)$, giving us:

$Pr(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots \cap A_n) = Pr(A_1)\cdot Pr(A_2|A_1)\cdot Pr(A_3|A_1\cap A_2)\cdots Pr(A_{n}|A_1\cap \cdots A_{n-1})\cdot Pr(A_{n+1}|A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots \cap A_{n})$

which is exactly what we wanted to show.

---

Smaller case to see it in action:  $Pr(A\cap B\cap C) = Pr((A\cap B)\cap C) = Pr(A\cap B)Pr(C|A\cap B) = Pr(A)Pr(B|A)Pr(C|A\cap B)$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I think your thought is correct.  They want to see an inductive proof using the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: "Your thought". Spelling aside, however, I think this answer is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks for the correction :)